# SelectCommand doesn't work when ControlParameter is not given

Tags: asp.net, sqldatasource, selectcommand, controlparameter

I have a textbox with id = txt_SearchLibrary which is also my controlparameter that I am using to filter my sqldatasource, I want to get all the results when I don't type something in my searchtext box, but below codes results 0 rows. I tried 2 way but both didn't work.

first one:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MyDbConn %>"
            SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Books] WHERE ([BookName] LIKE '%' + @searchText + '%') OR  @searchText IS NULL">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="txt_SearchLibrary" Name="searchText"
                    PropertyName="Text" Type="String" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

second one:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MyDbConn %>"
            SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Books] WHERE ([BookName] LIKE '%' + @searchText + '%')">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="txt_SearchLibrary" DefaultValue="" Name="searchText"
                    PropertyName="Text" Type="String" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Answer (score 0):

The Text property is probably "" or String.Empty, rather than NULL which you're checking for in your SQL statement.